# Facebook Graph API - issues with the publish_actions permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication

Facebook official docs mention that the **publish_actions** permissions is needed to publish on your FB stream open graph features (actions + objects).
Well, I'm getting a problem to make it work. On the docs it is mentioned that these features are rolling out slowly to all users and will be available soon, but for now, they should be available for the developer and the test users (at least until my actions/objects are approved). Well, this doesn't work, I get an OAuthException ("(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions or App must be on whitelist").
So to make it work, I must first go to the Graph API explorer, grant myself manually a permission (publish_actions) to get the token and only then it works(maybe it is buggy?).

The other option is to categorize my app as "game" and then it behaves as expected. They also say we should enable the Enhanced Auth Dialog, so I did, but that didn't help.

Bump

***Edit***

This was actually in main docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#authenticate)

To make it work, just use the FBML for the login button with the scope:

```
<fb:login-button width="200" max-rows="1" scope="publish_actions">
</fb:login-button>
```

Works only for test users and developers instantly, but I guess that when my actions/objects will be approved, I will be able to roll this to all of my users.

Comment: This was actually in main docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#authenticate)

To make it work, just use the FBML for the login button with the scope:

<fb:login-button width="200" max-rows="1" scope="publish_actions">
</fb:login-button>

Works only for test users and developers instantly, but I guess that when my actions/objects will be approved, I will be able to roll this to all of my users.